# flask - user input (login/password) to a python variable

Tags: input, authentication, flask

I'm trying to learn about login/password/user session stuff in flask.
i found this link and have been trying to understand the code it provides (on the bottom of the page, the largest piece of code).

http://thecircuitnerd.com/flask-login-tokens/

The link doesn't provide, though, the contents of the login.html file.

So far, the way i've been handling forms in flask requires me to specify to the render_template function what user input will be attributed to each python variable. But since the author didn't do it, i suppose his method of getting the user input should be different than that.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking - are you wondering how the `/login` route handler gets username and password?

Comment: "It's not really clear what you're asking - are you wondering how the /login route handler gets username and password?"
that's right
@SeanVieira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the login route handler in the code you linked you'll see that it uses `request.form` to get out two variables, `'username'` and `'password'`:

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login_page():
    """
    Web Page to Display Login Form and process form. 
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.get(request.form['username'])

        #If we found a user based on username then compare that the submitted
        #password matches the password in the database.  The password is stored
        #is a slated hash format, so you must hash the password before comparing
        #it.
        if user and hash_pass(request.form['password']) == user.password:
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            return redirect(request.args.get("next") or "/")        

    return render_template("login.html")
```

The simplest way to do this would be with the following HTML:

```
<form action="/login/" method="POST">
  <input name="username" placeholder="username">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

This will not re-populate the username if the user mis-types their username or password, nor will it give the user any indication that they failed to login.  They will just see the login form again.  However, this *is* just some example code, so it's understandable that the author chose to leave out useful code that would obscure the point he was trying to make.

Comment: do you have any links that will help me to understand these mechanisms better? thank you @seanvieira

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="/login/" method="POST">
      <input name="username" placeholder="username">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
<?PHP
@app.route("/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login_page():
    """
    Web Page to Display Login Form and process form. 
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.get(request.form['username'])

        #If we found a user based on username then compare that the submitted
        #password matches the password in the database.  The password is stored
        #is a slated hash format, so you must hash the password before comparing
        #it.
        if user and hash_pass(request.form['password']) == user.password:
login_user(user, remember=True)
return redirect(request.args.get("next") or "/")        

    return render_template("login.html")
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).